# How to spool all data in a column in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

While spooling using below setup, the output is coming broken at new line so all the data in a column is not getting into the file.

```
SET NULL 'NULL'
set serveroutput on size unlimited
set termout off
set long 1000000000 longc 60000
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SET LINESIZE 15000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMS OFF
SET NUMWIDTH 50
SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF
SPOOL logs.html
select * from some_table;
spool off
```

I tried a select query which has logs in one column which seems multiline so when I am spooling the same only the 1st line is coming in output and rest are getting truncated. I tried to set multiple options like very big line size etc but none helped.

The same query works fine in SQL Developer and I can see all the lines.

Sample data stored in column:

```
"SQL exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 for query: 

WITH  org_list AS (
  SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR (txt, INSTR (txt, ',', 1, level ) + 1, INSTR (txt,     ',', 1, level+1) - INSTR (txt, ',', 1, level) -1)) as org_id
  FROM ( select ','||:1||',' as TXT from dual )
    CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(txt)-LENGTH(REPLACE(txt,',',''))-1
 )
SELECT DISTINCT fdo.user_id
, fdo.user_name
 , (SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME
       FROM SI_USERS WHERE USER_ID = fdo.user_id) USER_FULL_NAME
 , NULL "fdo.role_id"
 , NULL "fdo.role_name"
 , NULL "fdo.activity_id"
 , NULL "fdo.activity_short_name"
 , fdo.activity_name
  FROM org_flow_qm_v fdo
```

Currently SQL*Plus spool shows only one line in the column:

```
SQL exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL     command not properly ended
```

How can I get the complete log/data in the spool file?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in 11gR2 under Linux. Maybe you have a platform clash and the whole column value is on a single line with no line breaks, and your text editor is truncating the output? Can you view the generated file through a browser?

Comment: I am spooling the file as html and regular text but still i see only the 1st line.

Comment: I am spooling the file as html and regular text but still i see only the 1st line only. My DB version 11.2.0.3 Ent Edition

Comment: But you still see it *where* - in your browser, or in a text editor/viewer, and which one? Which operating system? Does your value have just new lines, or new lines and carriage returns?

Comment: I think its new lines and carriage return might also be there.